# How to define the Graphql type for complex array

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql

I am having a headache about defining the correct return types for this complex array I am returning via Graphql.
I am also using the Nest.JS framework.

Here is my data:

```
[
 [ { Id: '1' }, [ [ { x: '01-02-2021', y: 12345 } ] ] ],
 [ { Id: '172' }, [ [Object], [Object] ] ],
 [ { Id: '173' }, 
  [
  [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],[Object], [Object] 
  ]
 ]
]
```

This is the Class I am trying to return, as [ Grouped ] for the resolver.

```
@ObjectType()
export class Grouped {
  Id: string;
  SumPerDay: SumPerDay[];
}

@ObjectType()
class SumPerDay {
  x: string;
  y: number;
}
```

This is however, returning null for both id and SumPerday.

Any thoughts about this would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the types.

So instead of returning the above array, I slightly changed the returning data into :

```
    "Grouped": [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "_data": [
      {
        "x": "Thu Sep 30 2021",
        "y": 0.02
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "172",
    "_data": [
      {
        "x": "Mon Oct 04 2021",
        "y": 2327.7599999999998
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed Oct 06 2021",
        "y": 172.91000000000003
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Now it is working.

Comment: Can u please add the type you define